# Randomly ocurring "The network path was not found"-Error while connection to SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, tfs, connection

I'm using Microsoft Team Foundation Server to automate my build and releases. I've got a task, which deploys the whole DEV-Platform every day and night (we're forced to deploy something around 30 applications at once since they depend heavily on each other). During the deployment, TFS connects to its own DB Server to get the Deployment parameters. I'm using the following Connect-String:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="Devdeploy"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Server=tcp:192.192.192.255;database=someDevDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=cooluser;Password=thatsnotmypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=myTokenizingApplication;Connect Timeout=60"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

The connect string does work. And it also doesn't. It's random, sometimes my two daily deployments work for a week, then one fails but the one later that day works again.

Sure it's a development platform, so the developers do make mistakes sometimes and my deployment doesn't work. But the error I'm trying to figure out is completely unrelated to the errors the human hand produces.

So the error I get when my connection string does not work (log from last night):

> 2018-02-07T00:42:24.2709713Z Unhandled Exception: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found

Availability of the SQL Server and his services are out of the discussion because if something's not working there I'd know it thanks to my monitoring.

What do you think causes this randomness? Maybe multiple connections at the same time?

Comment: `A network-related or instance-specific error` Have you double checked your network environment,  one fails but the one later that day works again should not related your configuration. Moreover, multiple connections at the same time seems also could be a possibility. To narrow down the issue, you could set up a test only with single connection for multiple times deployment.

Comment: my network environment definitely isn't the problem. Your idea about one single connection sounds good, but I'm afraid this will not work. But I can try to keep the connections as few as possible. Thanks

Comment: So I did a little testing with a powershell script to see if the multiple connections to the sql server is a problem. I ran the script in multiple instances while each of it made a connection each second. We think it's a problem with the DeplyomentAgent.